# Ember.js .refresh() not refreshing my page

Tags: ember.js

I am working in an old ember app and the functionality of what I am working on is that a modal is open, tags are selected and the modal is closed. The close modal action uses send to an action in the photos controller that has a refresh action on it but my computed properties in that controller are not getting rerun. I need the quickSearchTagNames computed property to rerun in order to fetch the new tags to display on this page. From reading the Ember docs it was my understanding that calling refresh in the controller should refresh that page.

favorite tags route:

```
 close() {
        console.log("TRANSITION")
        this.send("sessionChanged");
      },
```

photo route

```
sessionChanged: function() {
      console.log("Photo session change")
      this.transitionTo('franchisor.photos.index').then(() => {
        this.refresh();
      });
    }
```

computed property that is not reloading after refresh in the photos controller

```
quickSearchTagNames: Ember.computed('franchisor.id', function() {
      var franchisor = this.get('franchisor');
      var franchisorID = franchisor.get('id');
      const favoriteTagsPromise = this.get('favoriteTags').index({
        franchisorID
      });
console.log("IN quickSearchTagNames")
      const tagNamesPromise =
        favoriteTagsPromise.then(favoriteTags => favoriteTags.filter(tag => tag.get('favorite') === true).map(tag => tag.get('tagName')));
        console.log("tagNamesPromise", tagNamesPromise)
      return DS.PromiseArray.create({
        promise: tagNamesPromise
      });
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

> my computed properties in that controller are not getting rerun.

this is expected. `Route#refresh();` does only *refresh the `model`, not invalidate any computed properties.

For a CP to update you must either update a dependency key of the CP or run `notifyPropertyChange`. However in your case I think a CP is not the right thing.

I would consider to move the data loading out of the CP and have a method you call on `init` or `constructor` that sets a property. then you can simply rerun this method.